# Unix-like command-line shells: Get full command input/output history

Tags: shell, command-history

I'm looking to see if there is some smooth way (that is, not me just writing a wrapper for the shell) to get full logs of both everything I enter into the command-line shell and everything that gets output. Often I tinker a lot with various softwares, and this seems like it'd be a nice way to trace my steps back.

I use zsh, but I'm welcome to solutions even if they happen to be bash (or some other shell) specific.

Thanks!

Comment: if its just input, the 'history' command is great

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [`ttyrec`](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en) which records the input and output of the entire console session, and allows you to play it back.

Answer (score 3):

Look into sudosh. A link to the SourceForge page is: [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudosh/)

(There may even be a package, depending on your repos/disto)

You can "sudosh" into a shell and everything is recorded for that session. All sudosh sessions are recorded and saved with a date and time stamp appended to it automatically.

(You can even grep/search the contents of the sudosh recording)

You can then use sudosh-replay to play back a recording of the shell session, just like you were watching it happen in real time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `screen` (or `tmux`) and enable logging.

```
screen -L
```

Answer (score 2):

[`script`](http://man.cx/script) does what you want.

> **Script** makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.